# Image expansion with HTML & Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I saw this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/3t7j2/5/) and was trying to imitate it but it doesn't work on my pc or browser

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var current_h = null;
var current_w = null;

$('.resize').hover(
    function(){
        current_h = $(this, 'img')[0].height;
        current_w = $(this, 'img')[0].width;
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width: (current_w * 1.3), height: (current_h * 1.3)}, 300);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width: current_w + 'px', height: current_h + 'px'}, 300);
    }
);
</script>
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" class="resize" width="250"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me as to where did I go wrong ?

Comment: Have you added jQuery-library?

Comment: Update your code with what you added

Comment: Code updated according to James MArti-davis answer

Answer (score 1):

Put this below your CSS link, inside your `<head>` tags.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

What browser are you trying to get it working in?

**UPDATE:**

Wrap your code in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Code here...
});
```

Comment: At least this answer looks like answer, not the comment

Comment: mozilla firefox and chrome

Comment: In one of your browsers, when you go to Developer Tools, are you getting any errors?

Comment: @user2539745 wrap the code in $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Thanks alot. It worked. Good observation

Comment: Well, looks like I'd better write about `document.ready` there rather than create own answer

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the code of fiddle the entire function are inside of the "load" event.
Try that or ready function.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var current_h = null;
    var current_w = null;

    $('.resize').hover(
        function(){
            current_h = $(this, 'img')[0].height;
            current_w = $(this, 'img')[0].width;
            $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width: (current_w * 1.3), height: (current_h * 1.3)}, 300);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width: current_w + 'px', height: current_h + 'px'}, 300);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad idea to wrap this code in `document.ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.resize').hover(
        function() {
            current_h = $(this, 'img')[0].height;
            current_w = $(this, 'img')[0].width;
            $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width: (current_w * 1.3), height: (current_h * 1.3)}, 300);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width: current_w + 'px', height: current_h + 'px'}, 300);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Added `$(document).ready` to the javscript code and updated your code. Here is the new one

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var current_h = null;
var current_w = null;
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.resize').hover(
    function () {
        current_h = $(this, 'img')[0].height;
        current_w = $(this, 'img')[0].width;
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            width: (current_w * 1.3),
            height: (current_h * 1.3)
        }, 300);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            width: current_w + 'px',
            height: current_h + 'px'
        }, 300);
  });
});
</script>
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" class="resize" width="250"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```